# Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x68)

Tags: c, arquivo, xcode

Estou tendo esse problema na ide Xcode. Na linha 8 aparece o aviso

> Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x68)

O arquivo .txt se encontra na mesma pasta onde está o `main`.

```
void construir1(struct elemento **P_inicio){
    FILE *arq;
    struct elemento *p1;
    char c;

    arq=fopen("t1.txt", "r");
    *P_inicio = NULL;
    while ((c= getc(arq))!=EOF) {
        if (c!='\n') {
            p1 = malloc(sizeof(struct elemento));
            p1->x = c;
            p1->prox = *P_inicio;
            *P_inicio= p1;
        }
    }
    fclose(arq);
    return;
};
```

Comment: Compilei o mesmo código no Linux usando o gcc e funciona perfeitamente. Realmente se trata de algo do Xcode ou do Mac, se algum souber o que pode ser e como resolver seria de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realemente era algo do Xcode, ele não estava puxando o txt.
Para resolver fui na opção "Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run > Working Directory" e linkei a pasta onde fica o código e o txt. Fazendo isso o programa rodou normalmente no Mac.